# Grails render PDF file

Tags: pdf, grails, render

I am trying to render a PDF file in my web page but using the bellow syntax I get a weird characters combination.

```
render file: new File ("path/to/file.pdf"), fileName: 'myPdfFile.pdf'
```

Does anyone knows what do I have to add more than the line above?

Thanks

Comment: The explanation provided answers your question. You should accept it to close this topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Grails does this by default. 
Take a look at **PDF rendering plugins**. [This](https://grails.org/plugin/rendering) looks to be the freshest, but make sure it's compatible with your Grails version. 
If You are using Grails 3, [this](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/rendering/view) could be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I had the same problem yesterday but with some differences. I had to get to load a PDF from a Grails form in a new tab, using POST method to access a PHP script which generates PDF according some variables.

Anyway, I recommend you to check your header. If you get the binary file, for example, then you must define the header. So, we have for example:

Controller/Action:

```
    def generatesReport = {
        def url = StaticContextService.app.config.grailsPath.urlLocalServer,
        path = 'some/url/which/generates/this.pdf',         
        parameters = /* defining parameters bla bla bla */

        def bytes = SendHttpService.getYourBinaryHere(url, path, parameters)

        /* HERE IS MY ANSWER, properly */
        response.setContentType('application/pdf')
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length)
        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="yourPdfFile.pdf"')
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
        outputStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length)
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()        
    } // end method
```

There are many ways to define the header, and so you need to verify which settings are better for your demand (:

Don't forget to add the necessary libraries for your dependencies. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

in Grails 3, you can simply do

```
render file: new File ("path/to/file.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your suggested plugin? I am not able to use this dependency in my project. 1.0.0 Version does not exist, there are 2.0.0, 2.0.2 and 2.0.3 versions - but project compilation fails when I try to use them.

I have tried to download git sources and run them - website is up, but I also see error below:

```
Grails Runtime Exception

Error Details

Error 404: 
Servlet: grailsDispatcherServlet
URI: /
```

When I try to visit particular controller action it ends like this:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1337)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)

    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:31)
```