# Grails 3.0 public folder

Tags: pdf, grails

I am generating some pdf documents in Grails and saving the produced document in my Grails folder.

I would like to save the generated pdf in a public folder so that I can easily create a link to the newly generated file.

I don't to do something like this ([Grails render PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569758/grails-render-pdf-file)) but rather access the files directly from the browser.

My folder structure is as follows

```
.gradle
build
classes
gradle
grails-app
libs
out
pdf
src
.asscache
buildcradle
gradle.prperties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

Please feel to let me know if any modifications or things I should have done went missing.

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, if you use tomcat, is configuring `docbase` in your `conf/server.xml` inside `Host` configuration:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
    ...
    <Context docBase="/your/path/with/pdfs" path="/pdfs/" />
</Host>
```

And that's it, you can access your files from http://example.com/pdfs/my.pdf

Comment: thanks for the tip. I will give this a try and let you know how it goes.